# Mesh collider problem with two models next to each other

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

As you can check from video link I have a mesh created from two models, for some reason sometimes ball collides with middle part between two models, in the test I've run seen in video I've combine two models in Blender and merged vertices by distance, I've also tested putting two meshes next to each other (just in Unity without exporting to Blender) it was worse. I also set Default Contact Offset very low (2e-05) and collision detection as continuous but nothing worked

Any help is appreciated I also dont want to merge every model in blender so if there is a fix I can use in Unity and put models next to each other without problem it would be awesome

[Test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdfbFlAkIlk)

Answer (score 0):

Do you user Meshcollider or BoxCollider? If you use MeshCollider make sure they are marked as Convex. Always use simple collider if you can.

Comment: I am not using any other collider other than Meshcollider also when I tick Convex, colider doesnt handle walls it just creates a box around the mesh

Comment: That's the whole point of convex Mesh. Try to use box colliders and compose them together to achieve your border colliders. Test it out and if it works, change it everywhere

Comment: sorry but thats not the answer I'm searching, level shown in video is simple one so could be created with ismple colliders I admit however I will have curved paths then I wont be able to solve it by primitive colliders